# "Image corrupt or truncated" after PHP resize

Tags: php, mysql, image, resize, corrupt

I am attempting to resize an image before storing it as a BLOB in MySQL. FireBug tells me that the "Image is corrupt or truncated", although I am able to open 'tmp.jpg' after this runs. Here is my code:

```
    $fileName = $image['name'];
    $tmpName  = $image['tmp_name'];

    $img_orig = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmpName));
    $orig_width = imagesx($img_orig);
    $orig_height = imagesy($img_orig);

    $max_width = $max_height = 500;

    if ($orig_width > $orig_height && $orig_width > $max_width) {
        $new_height = $orig_height/$orig_width*$max_width;
        $new_width = $max_width;
    }
    else if ($orig_height > $max_height) {
        $new_width = $orig_width/$orig_height*$max_height;
        $new_height = $max_height;
    }

    $resized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($resized,$img_orig,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,$orig_width,$orig_height);
    ImageJPEG($resized,'tmp.jpg', 80);
    $instr = fopen('tmp.jpg', "r+");
    $img = addslashes(fread($instr, filesize('tmp.jpg')));
    $imginfo = getimagesize('tmp.jpg');
```

After the resize code, I insert into MySQL with this query:

```
$query = sprintf(
        "insert into images (filename, mime_type, file_size, file_data, category, priority)
            values ('%s', '%s', %d, '%s', '%s', 1)",
        mysql_real_escape_string($fileName),
        mysql_real_escape_string($imginfo['mime']),
        filesize('tmp.jpg'),
        mysql_real_escape_string($img),
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category'])
        );
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is the makeup of your table?  It could be trunicated because mysql can't fit the image inside the column, make sure to use bigblob or similar

Comment: I am using bigblob, and I also should have mentioned that the images were stored successfully before I added the resize code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are using `addslashes()` and then you are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, i think thats corrupting the file data

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.